# YouTube java api - v3

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to use the latest version of the youtube API (V3) but for some reason I'm getting casting exception when calling the list functions (for the different entities)

in the below example I'm getting the following exception when calling the execute method:

Code:

```
Youtube youTube = new Youtube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();

Map<String, Channel> channels = youTube.channels().list("id").setMine("").execute().getChannels();
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected collection or array type but got java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Channel> [key channels, field private java.util.Map com.google.api.services.youtube.model.ChannelListResponse.channels]

at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115) ~[guava-11.0.1.jar:na]

at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:534) ~[google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar:1.11.0-beta]

at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:352) ~[google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar:1.11.0-beta]

at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:588) ~[google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar:1.11.0-beta]

at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:291) ~[google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar:1.11.0-beta]

at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:268) ~[google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar:1.11.0-beta]

at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseAndClose(JsonParser.java:143) ~[google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar:1.11.0-beta]

at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser.parse(JsonHttpParser.java:90) ~[google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar:1.11.0-beta]

at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:501) ~[google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar:1.11.0-beta]

at com.google.api.services.youtube.Youtube$Channels$List.execute(Youtube.java:271) ~[google-api-services-youtube-v3alpha-rev13-1.8.0-beta.jar:na]
```

Any idea? I'm using the latest java client.

Thanks,

Efi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was just a recent, significant push on the server side that changed the response format for a number of services, and not all the client libraries have been updated yet to deal with that. Try refetching the Java client library [service definition for YouTube](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#YouTube_API) early next week and trying again.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem. Google just released a new client version which solve it (v3-rev2-1.8.0-beta)